# How to calculate inside of function and pass it into main using arrays

Tags: c

Currently I am working on some of homework stuff and I got stuck on point where i need to calculate Reciprocal of a Fraction

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reciprocal (int topnumber[],int botnumber[],float *argument[]);

int main(){
    int topnumber[3],botnumber[3],i,n;
    float argument[3];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      printf("Top number of %d fraction\n",i+1);
      scanf("%d",&topnumber[i]);
      printf("Bot number of %d fraction\n",i+1);
      scanf("%d",&botnumber[i]);
    }
    reciprocal(topnumber[i],botnumber[i],&argument[i]);
}

void reciprocno (int topnumber[],int botnumber[],float *argument[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
      &argument[i] = botnumber[i] / topnumber[i];
      printf("Reciprocal of a Fraction %d / %d is %f\n",topnumber[i],botnumber[i],argument[i]);
    }

}
```

I want it to write Reciprocal of 2/5 is 5/2 = 2.5 and I need it  to be calculated in function and then passed into main function using scanf to collect top and bot numbers with for loop

Comment: What's the point of a function if you call it only once? Why not define the `reciprocal` function as `float reciprocal(int itop, int ibase)` and then store the results in the float array within the loop?

Comment: That is the same thing that I was thinking but It was written in exam that you need void function and call it in main to calculate this

Comment: Does the exam require the function definition to calculate all the details in one function call (must use arrays and pointers), or does the exam require that the function calculate the reciprocal value? Does the function `float reciprocal(int itop, int ibase) { return (1.0 * ibase) / itop; }` not fit the requirements?

Comment: Exam requires use of function and array use as well with pointers

Comment: @Myst the point of a function that is only called once is readability and segmentation.  When executed in a debugger, you can step over the function to skip it rather than trying to continue to a certain line number.  When reading the code, you can clearly see which lines of code are related to which functionality.  You can easily refactor the code by moving the call site of the function.  You can add more invocations of the function as needed.  There are far too many good reasons to write a function that is only called once than can fit in this comment box.

Comment: @WilliamPursell , the function is a simple mathematical operation (`(float)a/b`). None of the reasons listed here apply. If the function was something like `io_reactor_initialize()` I wouldn't have given it a second thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand

> void reciprocal (int topnumber[],int botnumber[],float *argument[]);

must be

```
void reciprocal (int topnumber[],int botnumber[],float argument[]);
```

in *main*

> ```
> reciprocal(topnumber[i],botnumber[i],&argument[i]);
> ```

must be

```
    reciprocal(topnumber,botnumber,argument);
```

and

> ```
> void reciprocno (int topnumber[],int botnumber[],float *argument[]){
> ...
>   &argument[i] = botnumber[i] / topnumber[i];
> ```

must be

```
void reciprocal (int topnumber[],int botnumber[],float argument[]){
  ...
   argument[i] = ((float) botnumber[i]) / topnumber[i];
```

note the cast to *float* to do a float computation rather than a division between *int*

---

I also encourage you to check the *scanf* returns 1 to be sure a valid input was enter

Comment: Thank you It fixed the problem my teacher wanted me to somehow use pointers inside of a function and then convert them from memory in main thats how I think it was but It got me so confused haha

Comment: @MarinSpudić in _reciprocal_ the parameters are pointer, and you can use them as pointer modifying them rather than using array index in the loop, do you want I show you how to ?

Comment: Thank you for helping me there I now found out that I can cast to float !

Comment: @MarinSpudić yes it is needed to cast at least one of the value to divide, else the division is made between int and _after_ transformed to a _loat_ but too late

Comment: Thank you so much I did it !